# SQL Server Express restore backup error

Tags: sql-server

I'm running SQL Server Express 9.0.4035 on Windows 7, and am having the following problem creating a new database from a backup file I've been given.

In the Restore Database dialogue I enter a new database name and select the file to restore from.

I then get the following error:

`Directory lookup for the file "S:\SQLData\[new_db_name].mdf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).`

What is S:/\, and why is it looking for this [new_db_name].mdf file, which won't exist yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database backup contains the full path and filename of the original database. You simply need to change them to suit the server/system that you're restoring the backup to.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186390.aspx